# C to PHP unsigned char issue

Tags: php, c, char, unsigned

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to write this one line of code in PHP.  I've never run into anything like this in PHP before and would appreciate any help.

```
$OCTET_data->B[0] = (unsigned char) (ror8 ((unsigned char) (ror8 ($OCTET_data->B[0], 1) - 1), 1) - 1) ^ $OCTET_data->B[4];
```

Comment: What language is that supposed to be? Parts of it look like C, parts look like PHP. What is `ror8`?

Comment: What is that line of code trying to do?

Comment: It was C code converted to PHP, but I'm not sure what to do with unsigned char.  I know I should use the pack function, but I'm not sure what the best route would be in this particular example as far as implementation goes.

Comment: It's part of an encryption function for RSA securid.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to accomplish. Show the input data and the desired output data. Also, show the original C code so we can understand what it's trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure RSA doesn't provide a PHP library already?

Comment: There is an RSA authenticator that I believe is commercial as well as a PAM module, but this is part of a research project not to mention I believe the code could be implemented with either solution anyway.  Here is a pastebin link to the C code: http://pastebin.com/5gm5CQ1L

Comment: As far as I understand, the function `ror8(word, shift)` returns `(word >> shift) | (word << (8 - shift))`. Kevin, it is better to add this kind of information in the question.

Comment: I'm not really sure why my ror8 function call is relevant to the question of how to implement the pack function to replace the unsigned char tag, but here is a pastebin to my ror8 function.  http://pastebin.com/hAh2KipE

Answer (score 0):

I can't for the life of me figure out what you are trying to do.

But I think you are looking for the 'pack' function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

```
   $unsignedchar =  pack("C",$char);  // convert a char character to an unsigned char byte
```

Comment: I'd found that, but wasn't sure how to implement in this particular example.  For example what should I set $char to and should I simply replace (unsigned char) with ($unsignedchar)?

Answer (score 0):

The `(unsigned char)` cast in the original C code discards all bits not fitting in an `unsigned char` from the operand. The code obviously presumes that an `unsigned char` has 8 bits, thus the cast is equivalent to a bitwise AND with 2<sup>8</sup>−1, and you can write

```
$OCTET_data->B[0] = (ror8((ror8($OCTET_data->B[0], 1)-1)&255, 1)-1)&255^$OCTET_data->B[4];
```

or, perhaps a little more clearly

```
$OCTET_data->B[0] = ror8(ror8($OCTET_data->B[0], 1
                             )-1 & 255, 1
                        )-1 & 255 ^ $OCTET_data->B[4];
```